# Change default encoding order in locale -a

Tags: ubuntu, encoding

My ubuntu server output the following after a locale -a :

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
fr_FR.utf8
```

if i input `export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8`,it changes a little bit :

```
C
C.UTF-8
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
```

Main difference is that now, my rails tools works !
How can i change the encoding order so that next time i log in, the second order is already set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you can try for this, first try setting the LANG variable in `/etc/default/locale` to `fr_FR.UTF-8`

if that doesn't work for you try adding the LANG variable to each of the following

`~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile`

failing that you can regenerate your locale

`sudo locale-gen fr_FR`
`sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8`

Regen supported locale

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

then update the current locale

`sudo update-locale LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8`